# referring to the already fetched results in a query within the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

So suppose I have this table with 4 columns:

```
id  content  parent   timestamp
```

whereby the parent column refers to an id of another entry in the table

I want to accomplish the following:

Select the first 50 rows from the table Ordered by the following:

```
for each row,

if(parent = 0){
  add row to resultset, ordered by timestamp
}
else if (parent != 0){
   if parent is in the list of rows already fetched so far by the query,
   add row to resultset, ordered by the timestamp
   otherwise, wait until the parent gets fetched by the query 
   (assuming it gets fetched at all since there we're only getting the first 50 rows) 
}
```

this ordering logic is somewhat complicated, and I'm wondering if it's even possible to accomplish this using MYSQL ORDER BY statement in a single query WITHOUT having to resort to subqueries? Perhaps we could set and use variables? But how would the ORDER BY statement will be implemented?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible with an `order by` and quite difficult even with subqueries.  Extracting a subtree from a tree structure would have similar pseudo-code.  And, extracting a subtree is a hard problem.

Comment: is it one to one parent child? is it only one level deep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using variables which I incorporated into a procedure with a loop using an outer join and a temporary table to hold the unused inputdata but no subqueries.

Delete any old version of the procedure and set the delimiter

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS order_proc;
DELIMITER ;;
```

Start writing the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE order_proc()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 50;
DECLARE m INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE custom_limit INT DEFAULT 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pre_resultset;
CREATE TABLE pre_resultset LIKE input_data;
ALTER TABLE pre_resultset MODIFY id INT;
ALTER TABLE pre_resultset DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE pre_resultset ADD COLUMN iid INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;

SELECT n INTO custom_limit;
Set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = custom_limit;
INSERT INTO pre_resultset SELECT NULL,id, content, parent, timestamp FROM input_data WHERE parent = 0 ORDER BY timestamp;
Set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = default;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS unused_input_data;
CREATE TABLE unused_input_data LIKE input_data;
ALTER TABLE unused_input_data ADD null_col VARCHAR(1);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pre_resultset INTO m;
WHILE m<n DO 
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pre_resultset INTO m;
  TRUNCATE unused_input_data;
  INSERT INTO unused_input_data SELECT input_data.id, input_data.content, input_data.parent, input_data.timestamp, pre_resultset.id AS null_col FROM input_data LEFT OUTER JOIN pre_resultset on input_data.id = pre_resultset.id WHERE pre_resultset.id IS NULL ;

  SELECT n-m INTO custom_limit;
  Set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = custom_limit;
  INSERT INTO pre_resultset SELECT NULL, unused_input_data.id, unused_input_data.content, unused_input_data.parent, unused_input_data.timestamp FROM unused_input_data JOIN pre_resultset WHERE unused_input_data.parent = pre_resultset.id ORDER BY unused_input_data.timestamp;
  Set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = default;

  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pre_resultset INTO i;
  SELECT (IF( i = m, n, i)) INTO m;
END WHILE;
SELECT id, content, parent, timestamp FROM pre_resultset AS resultset;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pre_resultset;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS unused_input_data;
End;
;;
```

Change the delimeter back

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Run the procedure

```
CALL order_proc();
```